# problem with subdivision surface modifier

Tags: modeling, modifiers, subdivision-surface, bezier-curves

So Im making this model of BMO from Adventure Time.Being beginner and all I am not quite skilled with subdivision surface modifier(and all modifiers in general),so could somebody tell me a way to model these "fingers" so they dont look warped the way they look now.
Thanks!
[image: bottom of the finger is kind ofcrumpled]

Comment: That's a problem with topology of the mesh, not with Subdivison Surface modifier. As long as model has Ngons (faces with > than 4 vertices) most likely there will be problems when subdividing it. Decrease amount of edge loops on the finger end, increase their amount on the model itself.

Answer (score -1):

Use sculpting on the finger or try to roughly model them in edit mode and then use the subsurf modifier.

Comment: Can you expand this to explain exactly what they need to do to improve it? Currently they have *already* modelled it in edit mode and used a subsurf modifier.